# com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: Certificate chaining error while accessing a page through https in notes agent

Tags: java, ssl, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have following situation - I want to get page content using https request and java agent. However, I'm getting following error message:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: Certificate chaining error
```

I already imported internet certificates to my local notes cacerts file, but nothing changed.

However, when I'm running same code in Eclipse, using keystore with certificates downloaded from page I try to receive and it works fine.

I'm out of ideas, any suggestions will be appreciated!

===EDIT===

Dmytro Pastovenskyi's answer helped me, but additionally to get rid of protocol_version exception I had to use following code, setting version of TLS used:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
```

It seems nessesary to establish connection to some sites using 1.6 IBM JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue some times before.

1. It looks like IBM Domino server more strict when it check certificates. Our administrator who at the beginning said that chain is correct later found an issue with chain (and yes, it worked for .NET/JAVA and other platform, just not with Domino). Try to find some online tools that verify chain.
2. Before chain is fixed you can simply disabled certificate validation. I've an article how to do it (+ some other articles that may help you). Have a look here: [Disabling certificate validation in Java](http://dpastov.blogspot.com/2014/04/disabling-certificate-validation-in-java.html)

Comment: We have verified a chain with online tools and it seems valid. Meanwhile i tested my solution by importing paypal and google certificate. Both of them work fine. I will disable certificate validation as last resort..

What's more - it seems that issue is not connected with checking certificate but more with a handshake. We've tested this issue on pcs that haven't imported certificates, but error stays the same, all the time.

Comment: btw, I do remember that online tools did not prove that certificate was wrong, but for 100% I do remember that administrators confirmed that they uploaded certificated wrong (but it took them few weeks to check that).
We spent also few days trying to figure out if it is Domino certificate storage or anything else... but nothing helped.

Comment: Damn, I used disableCertificateValidation() from your blog (thanks for that one) but now I'm getting Received fatal alert: protocol_version exception. What's more, paypal seeems to refuse connection too. (Received fatal alert: handshake_failure)